# Partition for the first two continuous years without split in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table example. I dont have the column **Select** and I need to populate it. The concept is that the company gives a competition bonus for new or renew customers for two continuous years, so in the following I have two examples with the completed **Select** column I need. Please note only for type = 0.

```
customerid  year    id  type    Select
15774   2005    104684  20  
15774   2007    118639  0   0
15774   2007    118639  99  
15774   2011    149354  41  
15774   2013    162651  0   1
15774   2013    162652  43  
15774   2014    171617  0   2
15774   2014    171900  43  
15774   2015    175424  41  
15774   2015    175425  41  
15774   2015    176702  0   0
15774   2015    176703  43  
15774   2016    178783  41  
15774   2016    181054  0   0

23315   2014    173594  0   1
23315   2014    173595  43  
23315   2015    176587  0   2
23315   2015    176588  43  

22410   2013    162747  0   1
22410   2013    165819  43  
22410   2014    168750  0   2
22410   2014    172894  43  
22410   2015    176362  0   0
22410   2015    177648  43  
22410   2016    178272  41  
22410   2016    182631  0   0

23500   2013    171520  0   1
23500   2014    175980  0   2
```

any idea

Comment: Why does customer 15774 start at 0 but the other two at 1?

Comment: What else the `select` column will depend on?

Comment: Do you have a query that you have tried?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff because year 2007 dosn t continuous for two year on type 0

Answer (score 1):

I see.  You want the first two years that are adjacent.  This requires finding periods of adjacent years and then enumerating within them, all for `type = 0`.

So, `lag()` and some more logic is needed.  The following enumerates all such years for a customer:

```
select t.*,
       (case when type = 0 and lag_group = 1 and
                  row_number() over (partition by customerid, type, lag_group order by year) <= 2
             then row_number() over (partition by customerid, type, lag_group order by year)
             when type = 0 then 0
        end) as "select"
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_year + 1 <> year then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by customerid, type order by year) as lag_group            
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(year) over (partition by customerid, type order by year) as prev_year
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Comment: your answer is too close, for example for customerid 23500 is not working. Please note there is in case continuous 3 years so must take bonus for the first 2 years after a gap for 5 years and after that gap continuous for 2 or more years so must take bonus again for the 2 first years after the gap.